# this.innerHTML devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Al intentar obtener el valor del elemento seleccionado mediante el for y el evento este devuelve siempre undefined y queremos el valor solucitado mediante this ejemplo this.innerHTML. el cual devuelve undefined el problema es que se usa funcion flecha y no normal. Mas abajo esta la solucion

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('div')


for(i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
  div[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     alert(this.innerHTML);
  });
}
```

```css
.div{
  padding: 5px;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333
}
.div:hover{
  background: #333;
  color: aqua
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
    <title>this.innerHTML</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div">Hola mundo</div>
    <div class="div">Todos</div>
    <div class="div">Devolvera undefined</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Esto ocurre porque se utiliza una funcion flecha y esta en el this no nos da el parametro tanto innerHTML como value, title, etc.
La forma de arreglarlo es simple. Solo cambiamos la funcion flecha por una funcion normal.

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('div')


for(i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
//Solo cambiamos ()=>{} por function(){}
  div[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert(this.innerHTML);
  });
}
```

```css
.div{
  padding: 5px;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333
}
.div:hover{
  background: #333;
  color: aqua
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
    <title>this.innerHTML</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div">Hola mundo</div>
    <div class="div">Todos</div>
    <div class="div">Devolveran su valor</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Caso 1**

Si hacemos un console.log de **`this`** en el contexto de una función regular en JS obtendremos esto:

```
[object HTMLDivElement] {
  accessKey: "",
  addEventListener: function addEventListener() { [native code] },
```

Dado lo cual será valido que accedas al texto de cada `div` con la instrucción:

```
this.innerHTML
```

**Caso 2**

Sin embargo cuando hacemos un console.log de **`this`** en el contexto de una *arrow function* la salida sería como esta:

```
[object Window] {
  addEventListener: function addEventListener() { [native code] },
```

Donde notamos que entre las 2 existe diferencia del contexto de ejecución, por eso cuando intentas acceder a la propiedad `innerHTML` te da *undefined* ya que son contextos distintos.

**Propongo**

- que para evitar el ciclo for, envuelvas los 3 div en uno superior o padre
- Vigiles el evento en la etiqueta padre y a partir de ahi determines quien de los elementos internos lo desencadeno leyendolo a través de su clase que sería `div`

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      
        <title>this.innerHTML</title>
        
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="div">Hola mundo</div>
          <div class="div">Todos</div>
          <div class="div">Devolvera undefined</div>
        </div>
        <script>
          let divs = document.querySelector(".contenedor")
          
          divs.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
            if (evento.target.classList.contains("div")) {
              alert(evento.target.innerText)
            }
          })
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**EDICIÓN**

**Usando el método `getAttribute()`**

El método `getAttribute()` se puede aplicar en este contexto para extrer atributos como:

- `id`
- `class`

A través de la siguiente sintaxis:

```
evento.target.getAttribute("atributo-deseado")
```

**Usando la sintaxis de `evento.target.atributo`**

Sin embargo en este punto el acceso a los atributos de cada nodo se hace mas simple a través de la sintaxis de:

```
evento.target.atributo
```

Y los nombres de los atributos serían:

- `id`
- `className`

De hecho con esta última si imprimes así:

```
console.log(evento.target)
```

Podrás ver entre una gran cantidad de resultados, aquellos atributos que buscamos:

```
.............
id: "uno"
.............
className: "div"
.............
.............
.............
.............
```

Comment: Me parecio super bien la forma que propones sin embargo tengo una duda ¿Puedes acceder tambien a los atributos? mediante .getAttribute?

Comment: Te lo agradeceria @BetaM